# Xcode Split the Screen into 4 Giant Buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have figured out how to use auto layout to make all buttons visible, but I am stuck in one particular goal:

I am trying to divide the screen into 4 giant buttons, each button occupies 1/2 of the screen height and 1/2 of the screen width, with no spacing between each other. I tried setting constraints, but the buttons would not display properly.

Please see the two images I posted here, I want to make it so that the iPhone SE view looks the same as the iPhone 7 view. Last time I posted similar question my reputation got decreased, although I did not know why, I am someone who has just started on my own and am trying to figure things out so please advice. Thank you!

[image: iPhone7View]

[image: iPhoneSEView]

Comment: It would be useful to include some information on _how_ you set the constraints

Comment: For each button my initial attempt was to set the constraint to the edge of the screen to zero. So the top left button has constraint of 0 to the top and the left, the right bottom button has constraint of 0 to the bottom and the right, and so on... I thought I was able to set the constraints and then set the spacing between each button to 0 so that they can all adjust and fill the screen, but maybe I was wrong since I wasn't able to work it out :(

Comment: My guess is that you have described the positioning of the views via constraints, but you did not describe the _sizing_. You could simply select all four views and check equal widths/heights in order to verify that this is the case... or use Ryans answer to manage your constraints with stackviews.

Answer (score 2):

Following is the screenshot of constraints for your desired layout.
[image]

I'm gonna attach the storyboard also.
[File Download Link](https://dropfile.to/EWLRSS5)

Without Top and Bottom Views

[image]

[File Download Link](https://dropfile.to/PrsHguq)

Comment: @krunal it suppose to be half of the parent view so that's why you need 0.5. Otherwise equal to WHOM ? i mean with respect to which view equal ?

Comment: Top and bottom views complicate views hierarchy for no good reason.

Comment: @ArtemStepaneko you can do it without these view and in that case you would have to make the height of button as `0.5` with parent view as well. But i like to separate the views it's easy for modification.

Comment: How do I achieve the same effect without top and bottom views?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with constraints but it can also be easily done with stackViews.

```
let button1 = UIButton()
button1.backgroundColor = .red
let button2 = UIButton()
button2.backgroundColor = .blue
let button3 = UIButton()
button3.backgroundColor = .green
let button4 = UIButton()
button4.backgroundColor = .orange

let topStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [button1, button2])
topStack.axis = .horizontal
topStack.distribution = .fillEqually

let bottomStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [button3, button4])
bottomStack.axis = .horizontal
bottomStack.distribution = .fillEqually

let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [topStack, bottomStack])
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually

stackView.frame = view.bounds
stackView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]

view.addSubview(stackView)
```

Comment: This is a new thing to me but it looks like the solution! Do I add it in the correlated swift file under class HomeViewController: UIViewController {}? What if I want to set an scale aspect fill image for each button?

Comment: Yes you add it to maybe the viewDidLoad of your view controller. And you could still set your images for each button without an issue. Just maybe set `clipsToBounds = true` on the imageView of the button.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps: (*Very simple easy to implement*)

1. Remove all constrains from all your views (Orange, Red, Blue and Green)
2. Select All Four Views and assign `Top, Bottom, Leading & Trailing constraint` with constant value = 0 (with respect to position you have shown in your snapshot)
3. Select Orange and Red views and assign `Equal Width Constraint`
4. Select Blue and Green views and assign `Equal Width Constraint`
5. Select Orange and Blue views and assign `Equal Height Constraint`
6. Select Red and Green views and assign `Equal Height Constraint`

Look at this snapshot (Reference constraints, for all button are mentioned in left pane)

[image]

**Final View:**
[image]

Comment: I tried but it now makes the button super small and "pin" to the corner of the screen

Comment: @AndrewQin - I attached snapshot (by following steps i've explained) with it's result

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have gotten it to work perfectly.